# TIMESTAMP and SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

Is it a simple way to compare is field of TIMESTAMP type get into last **n** hours?
I can do the calculation based on the day and time, but is it possible something like

```
timestamp > SYSDATE - 1
```

(SYSDATE - 1) is yesterday, as far as understand, so that will check if timestamp is within the last 24 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to look for records within the last n hour, then subtract a time interval from the current time. For Oracle, the quantity of the interval must be in single quotes. There are many intervals you can use (hour, minute, second, day, year, month).

```
timestampfield > current_timestamp - interval '1' hour
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add/subtract non-integers too, e.g.:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - 0.5 FROM dual;
```

means 12 hours before now.

Comment: HH means 12 hour format, try this:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: Hali please edit your answer so I can give you the up vote you deserve.

Comment: thanks Hali - you got my up vote and I learned something from you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like

```
timestamp > to_timestamp(sysdate-1)
```

Comment: `to_timestamp(sysdate-1)` always ignores the time part, check this : 

`SELECT sysdate, to_timestamp(sysdate-1) FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

timestamp > cast(sysdate-1 as timestamp)